# Angular Spring Boot can't correctly pass variables to an endpoint

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, http

In my Spring Boot App I have an endpoint that is defined this way:

```
startFunctionality(@PathVariable Long clientId,@PathVariable Long projectId,@PathVariable Long functionalityId, @RequestBody(required=false) Map<String,Object> variables )
```

I want to pass a Map from Angular. I'm creating it this way:

```
 let variables = new Map();
     variables.set("A",1);
     variables.set("B",2);
```

Then I create my request this way:

```
 let data = {
        "variables":variables
      }
      const request: HttpRequestInterface = {
        apiUrl: 'clients/' + clientId + '/projects/' + projectId + '/functionalities/' + functionalityId + '/start',
        body: data
      };
      return this.httpService.get(request);
```

The get request is simply this:

```
public get(httpRequest: HttpRequestInterface): Observable<any> {
    const options = this.getBaseOptions(httpRequest);
    const observable = this.httpClient.get(this.apiBaseUrl + httpRequest.apiUrl, options);
    return observable.pipe(
      retryWhen((errors: any) => this.handleErrorsOnRequest(errors)),
      map((response: any) => this.getResponseData(response))
    );
  }
```

Since the `variables` request body is not required, I perform a check inside the method for the endpoint. The problem is that even if I set the body with my variables, the endpoint receives null. If I try to send the variables with Postman, the endpoint receives them correctly, they are not null.

Comment: the request url is correct, it worked with other types of data. What do I have to change? What is not proper?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the request body like :

```
 let data = {
        "variables":variables
      }
      const request: HttpRequestInterface = {
        apiUrl: 'clients/' + clientId + '/projects/' + projectId + '/functionalities/' + functionalityId + '/start',
        body: JSON.stringify(data);
      };
      return this.httpService.get(request);
```